# App does not respond to sqlite when it is installed in a real device

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have built an application in which I use sqlite to store data. It is running well in the simulator but when it run on a real device it stop responding to sqlite. Even the code is not responding to sqlite command..Here is my code..

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

//Create Database
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dirString=[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ABC.sqlite"];

databasepath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:dirString];
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasepath]==NO) 
{
    const char *dbpath=[databasepath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *createSQL="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QUESTIONS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTIONSLIST TEXT,ANSWER1 TEXT,ANSWER2 TEXT,ANSWER3 TEXT,ANSWER4 TEXT,CORRECTANSWER TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, createSQL, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");

        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }


}



[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

```
    -(void)xyz{


NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dirString=[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ABC.sqlite"];

databasepath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:dirString];

const char *dbpath=[databasepath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from questions order by random() LIMIT 1"];
    const char *query=[querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *questionField=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            questionView.text=questionField;

            NSString *option1=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            [answer1 setTitle:option1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSString *option2=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            [answer2 setTitle:option2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            NSString *option3=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            [answer3 setTitle:option3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            NSString *option4=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
            [answer4 setTitle:option4 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSString *option5=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
            correctAnswer.text=option5;
            correctAnswer.hidden=NO;


            [option1 release];
            [option2 release];
            [option3 release];
            [option4 release];
            [option5 release];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);

}
```

}

Comment: One of the main differences between the device and the simulator is, the simulator is case insensitive, the device isn't. Could that lead to your problem?

Comment: would you please elaborate, how can i correct it?

Comment: Also: does your code find the database file on the device; that is are you sure you copied the sqlite file to the real device as well?

Comment: Check whether the name of the file is spelled correctly in code. So on simulator you could load `abc.sqlite` even the file is called `ABC.sqlite`. On device this would not work.

Comment: @makaron please tell me how to copy sqlite file to device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoviceDeveloper:

```
please tell me how to copy sqlite file to device
```

If you want to do this, you need to have this file in the resources of your project: in this way it will be included to the app package and transfered to your device then.

Next step is to copy it to applicationDocumentsDirectory if you didn't do so before. Smth. like:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfYourDatabase.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NameOfYourDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL relativePath]]) {
    if (defaultStoreURL) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL toURL:storeURL error:&error];
    }
}
if (error)
    //handle it
```

EDITED:

With function:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: I have put the file in the resources and implement your code in viewdidload method.But it gives me a warning at  
        NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfYourDatabase.sqlite"]; //viewcontroller may not respond to applucationDocumentsDirectory

Comment: Got it.. just change the line with  
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfYourDatabase.sqlite"];
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];